# WCF - How can i make this config cleaner

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am new to WCF ,i have this config file and i really want to make it cleaner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="warConfig" name="Service.WarService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2222/war"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Service.IWarService"/>
        <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="authConfig" name="Service.AuthService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2222/auth"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Service.IAuthService"/>
        <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="warConfig">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="authConfig">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WarDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/WarModel.csdl|res://*/WarModel.ssdl|res://*/WarModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=BOGUS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WarDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

1) I am trying to get rid of those base addresses but when i run it i get this exception

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].
```

2)If i use svcutil.exe for both services i get some duplicate classes in the client services:

```
public partial class ObjectChangeTracker : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
public class ExtendedPropertiesDictionary : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>
public class ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Service.ObjectList>
public class ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Service.ObjectList>
public class OriginalValuesDictionary : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>
public enum ObjectState : int
public class ObjectList : System.Collections.Generic.List<object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the cleanliness of the configuration. It's a lot like sausage - you don't want to know the details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, but what about those duplicate classes
I use svcutil net.tcp://localhost:2222/war   and  svcutil net.tcp://localhost:2222/auth  and i get some duplicate classes in those 2 generated proxy. How can i handle this?

Comment: @boo: they're not duplicates - they're each in their own different namespace, right? Does your code compile?

Comment: No ,it does not compile. The error message i get is that those classes i enumerated in my first post are duplicated..The namespace is the same, should make those namespaces different?

Comment: The namespaces should be different if they are different service references. If you're going to use svcutil.exe, then you need to use the /namespace switch to map from the different XML namespaces to different CLR namespaces. If these are really the same type, then have you tried running svcutil _once_ with both WSDL files on the same command line?

Comment: I have just tried to execute svcutil with both WSDL files on the same command line, it was generated 1 app.config and 1 fie containing contracts and proxies, no duplicates. I think that this file will get huge so i think that your first solution, to use /namespace for mapping xml<->clr is the one to go for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you care how large the file gets? You're not going to be editing it - it's generated code.